What do CPU_User and CPU_System measure in MySQL?
When using profiling in MySQL, we can access various types of information, including CPU_User/System. However, I'm confused about how MySQL calculates these metrics.
For example, sometimes a query duration is ~5 seconds, but the combined CPU_User and CPU_System time is only 2 seconds. I understand that the remaining time could be due to factors like I/O wait time. But occasionally, I see that a query duration is 5 seconds, yet the sum of CPU_User and CPU_System exceeds the total duration!

As you can see in this example, CPU_User is around 0.02, but the duration is only 0.01!
Can someone clarify how MySQL measures this?

This looks like the old PROFILE warmed over.  There are only a couple of things of significance -- 'Sending data' is one of them; it provides nothing useful.  The 3 columns are probably similar to the 3 times in the OS's time command.
